# Exporting Web Site Gridview to Excel with Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, export

I'm trying to export a gridview from a website into a excel document.

I have to work with Visual Basic and that is a bummer because I'm sure I'll have this smoked out if it was C#.

I keep getting this error

> ScriptResource.axd?.... Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
>       at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd?
>       at PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerParserError [as _createPageRequestManagerParserError] (ScriptResource.axd.....

I have tried several different VB scripts for my button to export that gridview...  All result in the same parsing error.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Me.BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RData").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT vWosearch.TypeofWorkOrder FROM vWOSearch")
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    wogridviewex.DataSource = dt
                    wogridviewex.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Export_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            wogridviewex.RenderControl(hw)
            Response.Write(hw)
            Response.Output.Write(hw.ToString())
            Response.Flush()
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
        End Using


    End Sub
    Public Overloads Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
    End Sub
```

And Ive tried this one

```
Public Sub Export_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    wogridview.DataBind()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFileName.xls")
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim html As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(writer)
    wogridview.GridLines = GridLines.Both
    wogridview.RenderControl(html)
    Response.Write(writer)
    Response.Flush()
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    Response.End()


End Sub
Public Overloads Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
End Sub
```

The gridview from the ASPx page is simple

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="outerupdatepanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="ExportWorkOrders" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" onclick="Export_Click"/>

         <asp:GridView ID="wogridviewex" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" DataSourceID="SD1">  
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeofWorkOrder" HeaderText="Part Code" />
           </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sd1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:here%>'
        SelectCommand="blah enter my sql stuff">
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And now I used EPPlus API and still get the Parse Error.

```
   Protected Sub CreateXLSXFile(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateXLSX.Click
        GenerateXLSXFile(CreateDataTable())
    End Sub

    Public Sub GenerateXLSXFile(tbl As DataTable)

        Dim excelPackage = New ExcelPackage

        Dim excelWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DemoPage")

        excelWorksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(tbl, True)

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx")
        Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray())

        Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length)

        Response.Flush()

        Response.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Function CreateDataTable() As DataTable

        Dim dataTable As New DataTable("DT")
        'TODO: INSERT CONNECTION STRING 
        Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Rdata").ConnectionString)


        DBConnection.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * from vwosearch;"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, DBConnection)

        Dim adaptor = New SqlDataAdapter

        adaptor.SelectCommand = cmd
        adaptor.Fill(dataTable)
        DBConnection.Close()

        Return dataTable


    End Function
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: I wouldn't think I need a special library to take a grid view and turn it into a excel.  I installed the nueget for EPPplus but their doesn't seem to be any VB examples out their of exporting a girdview to excel.  I'm finding plenty of C# examples but I need something in VB that works.

Comment: The other thing users do with this grid view is filter it down to a select set of data and then they want to export it, the boss doesn't want them to copy and paste like they are doing now into excel, but the only example I have to work with doesn't export a Gridview.   Now My head is telling me not to export a gridview into excel but instead export a result of the query into excel.

Comment: I have implemented Epplus API into the site and still get a parsing error after I worked out all the kinds of the API to VB.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this occurring is that I had a

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="outerupdatepanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
```

On top and closing on Bottom, removing the ASP:updatePanel gets rid of the parsing error.  All 3 methods described above work so long as you remove the Updatepanel pieces from the aspx.